# Snowflake MERGE command with source table as Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I use pandas to load data into Snowflake tables.

In some cases, I wish that rows in a pandas dataframe that exist on the corresponding snowflake table would be updated, and new ones to be inserted.
I saw its possible in Snowflake using the MERGE command, but only when the source table is either a snowflake table or a subquery.

Is there any way to achieve this anyways?

Comment: Load the dataframe to a temp or transient table in Snowflake, first, and then merge from that.

Comment: Nice option, thanks!